# Server page based on weightage

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Suppose we have following pages and their serving weightage:

```
Page1    50%
Page2    20%
Page3    15%
Page4    15%
```

What would be a simple formula to serve pages based on their weightage? I am using Ruby.

Here is how I'm thinking.

```
actual_pct = Weightage 
tot_hits = Total hits against the URL
served_pct = Served percentage for each page based on tot_hits
served_to_actual_pct  = served_pct x 100 / actual_pct
```

Above will give me an array of pages with their `served_to_actual_pct`. Lets suppose I would be serving the pages based on their `create timestamp` when no page is served yet or more than one pages have the same `served_to_actual_pct`.

Based on this assumption I can sort this array on `create timestamp` and then on `served_to_actual_pct`. At this point the first page in the array would be the page to be served.

Comment: You mean serving different views from a controller, using these weightages?

Comment: They are totally different pages but are served against a SINGLE URL. But I need to make sure the pages are being served based on their weightages. For example if there are total 100 hits on the URL Page1, Page2, Page3 and Page4 should be served 50, 20, 15, and 15 times respectively. Does it make sense or I should explain it in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a weighted sample:

```
class Hash
  def weighted_sample
    target = rand * self.values.reduce(:+)
    key, weight = self.detect{ |key, weight| target -= weight; target < 0 }
    return key
  end
end
```

Add as many pages as you want as the keys of a hash with their weights as the value. Then call `your_hash.weighted_sample`. Keys with higher values will come up more often.

Comment: I have posted my result of weighted sample as separate answer due to formatting. Please look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this in your controller

```
random = rand
if random < 0.5
  render 'view_1'
elsif random < 0.7
  render 'view_2'
elsif random < 0.85
  render 'view_3'
else
  render 'view_4'
end
```

`rand` returns a random floating point number between 0 and 1. The if/else branching used ensures a probability of 50%, 20%, 15% and 15% for the four page views.

Comment: hmmm... This looks good. The first thing is that number of pages can vary - it could be handled, though. But I think we may need to go a bit further to distribute the hits exact to their weightages.

Comment: This should perform fairly accurately (+- 1%), but if you need _exact_ weightage, that would probably require storing some data on each page view, and deciding the next based on the already stored ones.

Comment: Yes, exactly I would be counting the every page view for individual page.